# Can you create a binding for a PopUpButton's selected value to a NSMutableDictionary's key (NSString)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, cocoa-bindings

You can create bindings on a NSView element to an delegate's instance variable, but can you create a binding for a PopUpButton's selected value to a NSMutableDictionary's key (NSString)? how you can do this in xcode 4?